# Splitting Nested JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

is it possible to Splice or split the following JSON utilizing JQuery or Javascript into two variables?
I am getting them from webmethod and I need them separated,
I want to do something like,
var x = JSON 1
var Y = JSON 2
is it possible?

```
{
"PtRegData": [{
    "RecID": 1277,
    "filenum": 15090248,
    "name": "Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizerasdasd",
    "msgcode": "info",
    "msgtitle": "Succsessful SQL Transaction",
    "msg": "Record has been updated succsessfully",
    "PartnerData": null
}],
"PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 0,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 13090701
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 15120996
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 170227111
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3416,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 11021602
    }
]}
```

**InTo**
JSON 1

```
{
"PtRegData": [{
    "RecID": 1277,
    "filenum": 15090248,
    "name": "Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizerasdasd",
    "msgcode": "info",
    "msgtitle": "Succsessful SQL Transaction",
    "msg": "Record has been updated succsessfully",
    "PartnerData": null
}]}
```

**And**
JSON 2

```
{
"PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 0,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 13090701
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 15120996
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 170227111
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3416,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 11021602
    }
]}
```

```js
var json = {
"PtRegData": [{
    "RecID": 1277,
    "filenum": 15090248,
    "name": "Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizerasdasd",
    "msgcode": "info",
    "msgtitle": "Succsessful SQL Transaction",
    "msg": "Record has been updated succsessfully",
    "PartnerData": null
}],
"PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 0,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 13090701
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 15120996
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 170227111
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3416,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 11021602
    }
]}


var json1 = json.PtRegData;
var json2 = json.PartnerData;
console.log(json1)
console.log(json2)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: are you deserializing it? or do you just want to split and send the info elsewhere? There are many options, but they the best solution depends on the usage further down the line

Comment: @Steen, yes I m deserializing but I need to have them separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
var json = {
"PtRegData": [{
    "RecID": 1277,
    "filenum": 15090248,
    "name": "Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizerasdasd",
    "msgcode": "info",
    "msgtitle": "Succsessful SQL Transaction",
    "msg": "Record has been updated succsessfully",
    "PartnerData": null
}],
"PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 0,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 13090701
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 15120996
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 170227111
    },
    {
        "RecID": 3416,
        "PrtStatus": 1,
        "ptfilenum": 15090248,
        "prfilenum": 11021602
    }
]}


var json1 = json.PtRegData;
var json2 = json.PartnerData;
console.log(json1)
console.log(json2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran the code (added above) but I get only the keys, not the whole JSON after each key

Comment: please check now. `var json1 = json.PtRegData;`

Comment: Thanks @parthtrivedi